# Remove all label elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr

In my application, I check if the user's browser is [HTML5-capable](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) and is able to display [placeholders](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute) in input fields (using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)). If so, I want to remove all `labels` from the HTML document in an automatized way, but I really don't know how.

In layman terms, if the user's browser supports placeholders I'd like to turn this:

```
<label for="email">
  Email:
</label>
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email">
```

Into this -in every occurrence-:

```
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email">
```

All I have is:

```
if (Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
  // Remove all labels from the HTML document
}
```

Until now I assigned `id`s to the labels and removed them one by one, but I'd like a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Don't do that! From the specification *"The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label."* Removing the label will mean that people can't check they put the right value in the right field (especially if it was put there by auto-complete) and will make it extremely difficult or impossible for anybody using a screen reader to know what they are supposed to enter into the field. (A good placeholder for your example would be "john.smith@example.com" not "Your email".)

Comment: @Quentin. That should be an answer. I'd upvote that answer

Comment: @Ben — While I think it is good advice, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Quentin Oh I didn't know that... Thanks for pointing it out. But then, aren't placeholders a bit redundant? Or their purpose is to show an example of the expected input?

Comment: Quoting from the specification again: *"The placeholder attribute represents a short hint (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry. A hint could be a sample value or a brief description of the expected format"*

Comment: @Quentin Cool. I have to stop taking popular sites as a reference for this things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are OK with using jQuery, this is an one-liner:

```
$('label').remove();
```

Example here - uncomment the one line in the JavaScript part to see the effect:

- http://jsfiddle.net/t42qs/

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! The non-jQuery answer worked too, it's a bit more messy though

Comment: The non-jQuery one only appears more messy because you can't see the 32KB of minified and compressed JavaScript provided by the jQuery library ;)

Comment: @Quentin but it's one of the best 32KB ever! :) (leaving the definition of "best" aside... :))

Comment: @Quentin well, I was using jQuery already. Therefore the more use I give to it, the better right? Besides, googleapis.com will deal with the bandwith :)

Comment: Running `$('div').remove();` in Facebook doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

First, build a table of the existing labels like so:

```
var labels = {}, tags = document.getElementsByTagName('label'), l = tags.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) labels[tags[i].getAttribute("for")] = tags[i];
```

Next, find input elements that have placeholders. For those that do, and have IDs, look for and remove the relevant label.

```
tags = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
l = tags.length;
var lb;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( !tags[i].getAttribute("placeholder")) continue;
    if( lb = labels[tags[i].id]) lb.parentNode.removeChild(lb);
}
```

Done! **No jQuery required!!** (because it is actually possible to do stuff in raw JS...)

Comment: Can't get this to work - grateful if you could clarify: http://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/mst9bjwu/

Comment: @geotheory This code is to remove labels. Not lists. You can't just randomly copy code that is remotely in the same category of "removing things" and assume it will work.

Comment: Then your solution doesn't reflect the title of this question and is going to waste people's time

Comment: @geotheory Excuse you, but the question *contents* are rather more important than the meagre summary given by the title.

Comment: That's irrelevant as I'm talking about the title not the content

Comment: @geotheory I have just approved an edit that updates the question title to reflect the actual question asked by the OP. This will be updated when approved by another user with edit permissions. Neit is correct in that the code provided meets the requirements of the OP given in the question, if not your more generic requirement. I suggest you ask a new question and the community will be glad to lend any assistance you may still need. Niet's answer is both correct, and on topic - it in no way wastes time.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say the title wastes time. Apologies Niet